# Как включить инструменты отладки в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, отладка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вернуть панельку назад.
Я делал через

```
Отладка->Параматры->Отладка->Общие->Показать средства среды выполнения в приложении
```

не помогло

Comment: [Практическое руководство. Использование визуализатора дерева WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd409789.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Путь на английском:

> Options→Debugging→General→Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML→Show runtime tools in application

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже делал это, и на английском лучше не стало

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил, что ваш путь, не отличается от моего.
Очень странно, что не работает. Потому что я только что проделал эту процедуру и в зависимости от того, стоит галочка или нет, соответственно эта чёрная панель, либо показывается, либо нет.
Вот есть похожая статья на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468509/strange-black-box-appearing-in-wpf-application